# React fetch local json file for testing does not work

Tags: reactjs, json, fetch, local

I'm trying to fetch a .json file from local, and

I get response 200 but with a body response of HTML: "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."

I have javascript enabled of course.

I don't want to import the file to simulate the real fetch.

How does local fetch work in react? How do I know if the fetch route is right? It doesn't give any useful error hint.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
        const dataFromLocal = await fetchData();
        console.log('dataFromLocal', dataFromLocal);
    }
    getData();
}, [])

const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('data.json');
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: CAn you add more context to your question and how are you fetching the json file. just show the code snippet .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how it works:

```
        const response = await fetch('data.json',
           {headers: 
               {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json'}
           });
```

just add this headers object to the fetch method and it works

Comment: The content-type header is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two possibilities based on the code you've shown:

1. Your server is responding with the contents of an HTML resource (likely `index.html`) as the response to the request for `data.json`, or
2. `data.json` looks like this, the JSON string you provided:

```json
"You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."
```

Is `data.json` in your project's `./public` folder?

Comment: Yes the .json is in the public folder. However i found the solution. The problem was that the fetch need the headers object. Ty for you response.